# Uncaught type Error by jQuery Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, typeerror

i have a problem on the following site: http://www.turtle-esport.de/v3

In the Console is this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

I hope anyone can help me to find the failure.

Comment: Your script is not loading `$.flexslider` or `$.fn.flexslider`. Strange!

Comment: Looks like the version that you have is corrupt. Try getting the latest one from: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider-min.js and see if that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **really** the answer! Looks like the version you are loading for FlexSlider is corrupt. Please try to get a fresh copy from [GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider-min.js)'s repository. Coz that works!

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because of 2 reasons:
1. You are adding more than 1 jquery library, remove older jquery and only 1 latest jquery 
2. Place allother scripts below jquery

Currently your jquery is conflicting with one another and so you are seeing error in your console

Comment: THX! I dont see the second Jquery Library! That was the issue ;)